# Liquibase incorrectly reads "--" symbols inside SQL script

Tags: sql, plsql, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I have next Liquibase formatted SQL script with PL/SQL block.

```sql
--changeset TASK-NNN-create_new_tasks endDelimiter:\\
DECLARE
    email VARCHAR2(60) := 'some_person@example.com';
BEGIN
    CREATE_TASK(
        'new_task_1',
        'python task_executor.py --processor-name "new"',
        'New task 1',
        REPORT_TO => email
    );
    CREATE_TASK(
        'new_task_2',
        'python task_executor.py --processor-name "new_2"',
        'New task 2',
        REPORT_TO => email
    );
END;
\\
```

But Liquibase interpretates it incorrectly because of double dashes in the second argument values of *CREATE_TASK* function calling.

```sql
DECLARE
    email VARCHAR2(60) := 'some_person@example.com';
BEGIN
    CREATE_TASK(
        'new_task_1',
        'python task_executor.py 'New task 1',
        REPORT_TO => email
    );
    CREATE_TASK(
        'new_task_2',
        'python task_executor.py 'New task 2',
        REPORT_TO => email
    );
END;
```

What do I have to do so the argument would be valid?

Comment: Welcome to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It reads it perfectly as it should. `--` in SQL is a comment.

Comment: @Shmiel not if it's inside a string literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but Liquibase thinks that "--" inside value brackets is a comment start mark. Also found out that Liquibase shrinks comment sections by default.

So I used "stripComments" option by disabling it and the new beginning of a script is next.

```sql
--changeset TASK-NNN-create_new_tasks endDelimiter:\\ stripComments:false
DECLARE
    email VARCHAR2(60) := 'some_person@example.com';
...
```

After that SQL script proceeds as expected.